# Conjugation is not expressible in terms of polynomials

Tags: matrices, algebraic-geometry

In order to convince myself that the set $U(n)$ of unitary matrices (matrices with columns that are orthonormal under the complex inner product) is not an affine variety in $\mathbb{C}^{n^2}$, I need that the conjugate of an entry $\overline{x}_{ij}$ cannot be expressed using polynomials. If we say that complex polynomials have to be finite sums of monomials of the form $cx_1^{e_1}\dots x_n^{e_n}$ where $c \in \mathbb{C}$, $e_i \geq 0$, then is this really enough? It seems a little slippery.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That conjugation is not expressible in terms of polynomials comes from the Cauchy–Riemann equations, but that is not what you need to prove.
You need to prove that the set $U(n)$ cannot be defined by a system of polynomial equations in the entries of the matrix.

Here is a simple proof. Consider the set $X$ of matrices $(a_{ij})$ such that $a_{ij}=\delta_{ij}$, except for $i=1, j=1$. Then $X$ is an affine variety in $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$. If $U(n)$ is an affine variety, then so is $Y=X \cap U(n)$. But $Y$ corresponds to the unit circle in $\mathbb C$. However, the unit circle is not an affine variety in $\mathbb C$, because those are either $\emptyset$, $\mathbb C$, or a finite set of points.

Comment: Right. That is, the standard definition of $\text{U}(n)$ involves functions which are not polynomials, but this doesn't prove that some more esoteric definition can't be used which does.

Comment: Yes, that is a good point. Good, so the fact that the standard definition does not work by the Cauchy-Riemann equations answers my original question.. so how does one go about showing that is not possible to define $U(n)$ by polynomials, even with an alternative definition?

Comment: @Fahad, try embedding $U(n-1)$ into $U(n)$. In other words, find an *algebraic* subset of $U(n)$ that is isomorphic to $U(n-1)$. If $U(n)$ was an algebraic set, then $U(n-1)$ would be too, and you could go all the way down to $n=1$, which gets you back to $z \bar z=1$ not being an algebraic set over $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that, though it sounds elaborate for the exercise I'm attempting. It is only the second exercise in _An Invitation to Algebraic Geometry_ by Smith & Kahanpää so it seemed like they were after the conjugation idea, judging from the difficulty of other exercises and the level of content in that chapter.

Comment: @Fadah, I've added a simple proof to my answer.

Answer (score 5):

<s>Probably</s> Perhaps the most conceptually straightforward explanation of why $U(n)$ is not an affine variety over $\mathbb{C}$ is the following: with respect to the complex topology (the usual topology -- not the Zariski topology!) $U(n)$ is compact, whereas it can be shown that a variety $V_{/\mathbb{C}}$ is such that $V(\mathbb{C})$ is compact (with respect to complex topology) iff $V$ is *complete*.  In particular, a complete affine variety is finite, which $U(n)$ evidently is not.

Of course all of these facts require (nontrivial) proof.  If I am remembering correctly, they are well treated in Shafarevich's text on algebraic geometry, for instance.

Comment: You're right, it is conceptually straightforward, though I can't say I have met any of those facts yet! I will keep the proof in mind for when I do.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a proof that $U(n)$ is not an affine variety in $\mathbb{C}^{n^2}$: If $X \subset \mathbb{C}^N$ is a smooth affine subvariety of $\mathbb{C}^N$, then, at every point of $X$, the tangent space to $X$ will be a complex sub-vector-space of $\mathbb{C}^N$. (Proof: The tangent space to a polynomial hypersurface is a complex sub-vector-space; the tangent space to an intersection is the intersection of tangent spaces. This argument also works for singular varieties if you use the [Zariski tangent space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski_tangent_space).)

At the identity, the tangent plane to $U(n)$ is the Hermitian matrices. Mutiplyling a Hermitian matrix by $i$ does not give you a Hermitian matrix, so $U(n)$ is not an algebraic subvariety.

Comment: To paraphrase this a bit, it seems to me that you are saying: if $U(n) \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ were a complex variety, then by homogeneity its set of $\mathbb{C}$-points would be a complex submanifold of $\mathbb{C}^n$ and thus its tangent spaces would be $\mathbb{C}$-subspaces...which they're not.

Comment: Thank you! This is a very nice proof but as with Pete's answer, I have to say I have not met that result yet, nor even looked at tangent spaces properly.. it is on the agenda though.